# App Script - Get Redirect link from API payload request - DEFINITIVE SOLUTION

Tags: google-apps-script, response, fetch-api, payload

I want to get a data that need to click a button to request.
here is the website
http://secure.senave.gov.py:8443/registros/servlet/com.consultaregistros2.prod_agro2

Just click the button "excel" and it generate an archive with all site content.

Ok.

Opening the development panel (Press F12 - Google Chrome) you can see by Newtwork content, all header and the payload request information.

I understand to get the data from the file, I need use UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options) to get the response. Where the var "Options" define headers and payload content.

I don´t know how I can make it works. I can´t get some response from the site about the solicitation. It only returns the same every data always (the general data from the web site) in html format.

And I don't know what it´s better... get the redirect link to the excel file generated or I get the data before the file generate, getting de API data response.

I´m reading a lot of StakOverflow posts about this question, and can't make a solution. Could someone help?

here it's my code that does not work

```
function myFunction() {
  
  let url = "http://secure.senave.gov.py:8443/registros/servlet/com.consultaregistros2.prod_agro2" 

  var options = {   
      'method': "POST",      
      'payload':
        JSON.stringify({
          "MPage":false,
          "cmpCtx":"",
          "parms":[0,"P","","",0],
          "hsh":[],
          "objClass":"prod_agro2",
          "pkgName":"com.consultaregistros2",
          "events":["'DOEXPORT'"],
          "grids":{"Grid1":{"id":36,"lastRow":20}}
          })            ,
             
  }
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
  Logger.log(response)


}
```